# How can I make dask distributed forget specific keys?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I do not see a way to have the scheduler forget keys that were previously used in an executed dask graph. Minimal example:

```
client = Client("127.0.0.1:8786")

def f():
    raise KeyError()

dsk = {'A': (f,)}
client.get(dsk, 'A') # raises KeyError
```

If I go back to fix a bug and resubmit the graph:

```
def f():
    return True

dsk = {'A': (f,)}
client.get(dsk, 'A') # still raises KeyError, but:

dsk = {'A1': (f,)}
client.get(dsk, 'A1') # returns True
```

I understand that this is the correct behavior, since f is already pickled and sent to the scheduler as is with the initial get call. Is there a way that I can have the scheduler forget 'A' before resubmission (without full restart)?

Comment: Nice question!  I really appreciate the minimal example.  I found this interesting to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two issues here:

#### A future exists

The scheduler *does* clear out keys pretty aggressively once no future points to them.  In this case it looks like the KeyError and traceback raised in the `get` call maintain a reference to the temporary future, which is unfortunate, given that it also maintains a circular reference back to them (I'd consider this a bug).  If you were able to clean those up then things would probably be fine.

#### Cancellation policy doesn't forget exceptions

I was going to suggest that you can explicitly clear out state creating and cancelling a future

```
from dask.distributed import Future
Future('A').cancel()
```

Unfortunately for you it looks like current policy is to remember exceptions even past cancellation.  You might consider [raising an issue for this](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/new)

#### Or just use delayed

It's rare to see people use custom graphs unless they are integrating with *some other* graph scheduling system.  Most users use [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html) which handles all of these issue for you.  In this case dask.delayed would construct a new key for you, as you have done in your example with `A1`, but it would all be hidden behind a comfortable usability layer.